# Ionic 4 routing issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have started a new ionic4 ("@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.19") app with tabs template. Then i added a new tab and in this tab i display some data in a list. Every list item redirect to a detail page.

When i go to a detail page everything works fine. Then i go back to the list view. If i want to go again to a detail page, this not work (only after reload the whole app).

Here is my code:
tabs.router.module.ts

```
...
  ,
  {
    path: 'tab3',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../account/account.module#AccountPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        loadChildren: './account-detail/account-detail.module#AccountDetailPageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

tabs.page.html

```
...
<ion-tab-button tab="account">
  <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>account</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
...
```

and my list

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let account of accounts">
  <ion-item routerLink="detail/{{account.id}}">
    <ion-label>
      <h3>{{account.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{account.capital | currency}}</p>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="end">
    <ion-item-option>Bearbeiten</ion-item-option>
    <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="onDelete(account)">Löschen</ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link to child route is available only under the context of parent route. 
Use the child link to details this way:

```
<ion-item routerLink="/account/detail/{{account.id}}">
```